# Subgroups of Cyclic $p$-Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

**Theorem** Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$, generated by $x$. Then every subgroup of $G$ is cyclic.

The proof is as follows: let $H$ be a proper non-trivial subgroup. Then there exists a smallest positive integer $m$ such that $x^m\in H$. Let $h\in H$ be arbitrary. Then $h=x^i$ for some $i$. If $i$ is not a multiple of $m$, write $i=mq+r$, $0<r<m$. Then $h=x^i=x^{qm+r}$, and $x^r=(x^{m})^{-q}.x^i\in H$, where $0<r<m$, a contradiction to choice of $m$. *q.e.d*

Suppose $G$ is cyclic group of order $p^m$. Then how can we prove the theorem? (I want to prove the theorem within the category of Cyclic $p$-groups.)
The proof I proceeded is as follows:

Let $1<H<G$, and $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $x^{p^m}\in H$. We show that $H=\langle x^{p^m}\rangle$. Let $h=x^i\in H$. If $i$ is not a multiple of $p^m$, then $i=qp^m+r$ where $0<r<p^m$. Then again $x^r\in H$ (as above), with $0<r<p^m$. This is not a contradiction, since $r$ may not be a power of $p$.

So, how can we prove theorem for cyclic $p$-groups?

Comment: Why do you need an additional proof?  If you've already proven it for all cyclic groups then you've proven it for cyclic groups that happen to have order a power of $p$.

Comment: FYI, the problem with your altered proof is that you haven't shown that every element of $H$ is of the form $x^{p^m}$ for some $m$, so you should take $m$ to be the smallest integer such that $x^m \in H$, just as you do in the general proof.  After you've proven that $H$ is cyclic you can go back and show that in fact $m$ was a power of $p$.

Comment: My current focus is only on $p$-groups. I want to prove some basic theorem for cyclic $p$-groups first, one of them is above. (I know general theory of finite abelian groups, and their classification upto isomorphism, with proof.)

Comment: Why do you want to do this separately for $p$-groups? As already noted, the exact same proof carries over.

Comment: I am sorry! my current study is the theory of $p$-groups. I inspired by a paper of Frobenius, who proves Sylow theorem, saying that Sylow in his proof had considered the groups to be substitution(permutation) groups and uses Cauchy's theorem, whereas Frobenius consideres only abstract groups and avoids use of Cauchy's theorem. By these thoughts of Frobenius, I am focusing my attension only on $p$-groups.

Comment: That still does not explain why you don't want to use the original proof. It carries over directly. The part you are missing is that you should not focus on powers of $p$ at first, but just do precisely as in the other proof. Then in the end, you have concluded that the subgroup is cyclic. And finally, that it is cyclic of prime power order is trivial as it is a subgroup of a $p$-group.

Comment: Sometimes considering a smaller class of groups simplifies the proofs of some theorems, but in this case I don't think that's true.  I think the general proof isn't going to get any simpler just because you assume the group is a $p$-group.